# Jenkins trigger parameterized cron with different parameter values for different branches

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have the following code as part of my declarative pipeline:

```
String CRON_SETTINGS = BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(master|.*release.*)/ ? '''30 23 * * * % param1=value1''' : ""

pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'param1', choices: ['value1', 'value2'], description: 'param')
    }
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron(CRON_SETTINGS)
    }
}
```

Currently the Cron behaves in the following way:
every night at 23:30 PM a build of the job is built if my branch name is master or if it contains the string 'release', always with the value of param1 set to value1.

What I would like to achieve is this:
In case the barnch name is master, run the cron with value1 set to param1 parameter,
However, if the branch name contains 'release', then run the cron with value2 set to param1 parameter.

Would apprreciate your help to achieve this,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer and I haven't tested this, but how about using a [switch statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_switch_statement.htm)?

```groovy
switch (BRANCH_NAME) {
    case 'master':
        cronSettings = '30 23 * * * % param1=value1'
        break
    case '.*release.*':
        cronSettings = '30 23 * * * % param1=value2'
        break
    default:
        cronSettings = ""
        break
}


pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'param1', choices: ['value1', 'value2'], description: 'param')
    }
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron(cronSettings)
    }
}
```